# “No map found” error when running NativeScript Angular 2 app

Tags: nativescript

I’ve got a really weird error when trying to run an app built with NativeScript and Angular 2. Here’s the error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:342:26:
Unhandled Promise rejection: No map found ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: No map found undefined
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:344:22:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): No map found
```

The error occurs when the app starts up. I’m using `nativescript-angular` version `1.1.2` and I’m including `zone.js` version `0.6.21` in my devDependencies. Here’s my full `package.json`: https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-photos-near-me/blob/6a201b05e91687618670a79e0a56ababc71572d7/package.json.

Any idea what might be up? I’m not actually using zones explicitly in my app, so I’m very curious why I’m getting this app here but not in new NativeScript Angular apps I start from scratch.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So as soon as I posted this I figured this out. The problem was an innocuous looking call to the Mapbox plugin’s `unhide()` method.

I assumed “map” was referring to some RxJS or Array value, when it was actually referring to an actual map. Who knew?